# Empty index.php prints question mark with only <?php ?>?

Tags: php, apache

Why when I put

```
<?php ?>
```

on an empty index.php it prints a question mark "?", this has never hapenned to me, does any of you know why ? I have nothing on the index.php file but this  also if i remove the last ?> the question mark keeps appearing.
Note: I have Apache, PHP on Windows.
Any Idas? I have years working with PHP, is this a matter of the CLR or something?
Also when I put this tag method it does not shows the "?" and it works fine:

```
<script language="php">  
echo "This is HTML script tags.";  
</script>
```

Comment: View source and see what's being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is usually about UTF-8. Download Notepad++, open the file, and in the Encoding menu select Convert to UTF-8 without BOM and save it.

Comment: Yes, I tried openning it with notepad++ and it appeared the questin mark at the very beginning: ?<?php ?>. It´s kind of weird I am using phpStorm and this have never happened, will verify settings. Regards!

Comment: you are welcome be careful this problem is serious. you should do this for all your php files ;)